# Thread Scheduler Error Visual Studio 2013 vs 2015

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++, mutex

I recently upgraded some projects from VS2013 to VS2015 and I have found some problems with my threaded code. The issue seems to be that a thread that is waiting on a mutex to get unlocked is not getting control when another thread unlocks the mutex. Since the other thread is a loop that locks the mutex, does something, then unlocks it, the result is that thread running the loop many times and the other thread waiting >10sec for control. Below is a very small sample program that reproduces the bug for me.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex print_guard_;
int i = 0;

void RenderLoop()
{
    while (true) {
        print_guard_.lock();
        std::cout << "Render: " << i << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
        print_guard_.unlock();
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}


void Print()
{
    print_guard_.lock();
    std::cout << "Main Thread: " << i << std::endl;
    print_guard_.unlock();
}


int main()
{
    std::thread* thread_ = new std::thread(RenderLoop);
    while (true) {
        Print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error occurs both with and without the yield command in the RenderLoop function. In Visual Studio 2015 I get something like:

```
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
... (continues for a few seconds or longer)
Main Thread: 0
Main Thread: 0
Main Thread: 0
Main Thread: 0
Main Thread: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
Render: 0
...
```

and on VS2013 I get

```
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
Render: 0
Main Thread: 0
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to force the thread to give up control?

Comment: `Below is a very small sample program that reproduces the bug for me.` I very much don't think this is a bug. If you want a guarantee that a lock is not hogged by one thread then you need to use something like a condition_variable or maybe a simple atomic counter with a busy-loop in case it's a highly contested lock.

Comment: It seems that condition variables only allow you to "wake up" a thread where I really need the ability to notify a thread to sleep. Any ideas on that?

Comment: What is really confusing to me is why the mutex control isn't queued. Main thread requests the lock, but somehow RenderLoop keeps getting the lock while MainThread is waiting.

Comment: well the Main thread may actually run on another core, try to get the lock but not be able to get it and then yield itself. Scheduling is non-trivial especially in a multi-core context.